# Downsampling text documents

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, downsampling

I have two classes with 1000 documents in class one and 40000 documents in class two. The documents consist of texts.
I want to use these texts in a neural network. But of course there is a unbalanced-dataset-problem. Each classifier would through all documents into class two and say "I have a great accuracy of 97.5%.

Do you know if there are any implementations that check the document-similarities in class two and kind of clusters them and then just drops documents of each cluster proportional to its cluster size?

Or do you know similar approaches with the same target?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details.  What does your classifier do?  Are you classifying by sentiment, topic modeling, emotion, document type such as news or blogs, phrases, etc.?  Are you looking for specific words?

Comment: My classifier should classify by sentiment. Currently I'm using a CNN.
The documents have pretty long texts, so currently I'm looking for common keywords in all documents of one class (just testing approaches like correlated pattern/sequence mining, simple document-frequency approaches etc.) and then filtering the sentences that contain at least one of these keywords. I'm using these filtered sentences as input for the CNN.

Comment: It sounds like you want N-Grams.  Have you tried using them?

Comment: If you have the time, a simple way to address this concern would be to use a random, say 700 docs from class1 and a random 700 from class 2. Train a bunch of networks on *different* randomly sub-sampled docs, and compare the hidden activations. If they're similar, you're in business. If they're not, you need a principled way of assessing the classes -- maybe by keyword like you mention -- to do the sub-sampling.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding from your comments is that you have 50k documents labeled as either positive or negative in sentiment. You would like to reduce the larger class from 40k to 10k by clustering the documents and selecting a fraction of documents from each cluster.

If that's right, the following approach ought to do what you want?

- Produce TF-IDF representations for the 40k documents. (You can make the TF-IDF representations from the keyword sets you already identified.)
- Apply an agglomerative hierarchical clustering technique until you have only 10k branches remaining. You can use cosine similarity between TF-IDF vectors as your similarity metric, and use the centroid as the TF-IDF vector for a document group. (If implementing yourself: remember that you can retain almost all of your pairwise similarity calculations between rounds, or you will do a lot of unnecessary recalculation!)
- From each cluster containing multiple documents, choose one document to retain.

That said, I agree with gerowam that a random downsampling strategy would likely be easier, faster, and likely just as effective, but you're welcome to try it and report back.